# Evaluate calculation with interpretor but value to big

Tags: java, biginteger, beanshell

I'm using the BeanShell Interpreter in Java to solve string-calculations. the problem is that I do some parsing by myself which can't be done by the interpreter and store the partial result in an BigInteger. Then I piece together everything and give it the interpreter to resolve but the numbers I receive with `BigInteger.toPlainString()` are to big for `interpreter.eval(...)` because I receive the folling error message:

```
 Parse error at line 1, column 10 : Error or number too big for integer type: 2432902008176640000
    Parse error at line 1, column 10 : Error or number too big for integer type: 2432902008176640000
```

The calculation string is constructed like this:

```
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(/*very big number*/);
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(/*very big number*/);
    String s = x.toPlainString() + "+" + y.toPlainString();

    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
    i.eval("result = " + s);
    s = i.get("result").toString();
```

I know in this case I could simple add the numbers by the provided function of BigDecimal, but in my case the calculation is way more complex!
Is there a possible workaround so I can use the beanshell evaluator with huge numbers too?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your scenario is really more complex so you can't just do this without BeanShell:

```
s = x.add(y).toString();
```

If this is the case, you should know that you can access the `BigDecimal` objects directly from your expression:

```
i.set("x", x);
i.set("y", y);
i.eval("result = x.add(y);");
s = i.get("result").toString();
```

You can even do:

```
String someBigNumber1, someBigNumber2;
// Set the number strings
i.set("xStr", someBigNumber1);
i.set("yStr", someBigNumber2);
i.eval("import java.math.BigDecimal;");
i.eval("result = new BigDecimal(xStr).add(new BigDecimal(yStr));");
s = i.get("result").toString();
```

BeanShell uses on-the-fly AST parsing and reflection to interpret instructions and resolve methods based on concrete types of 1) the things passed into it and 2) things returned by methods. This is very similar to how various scripting languages have `var` variables that aren't explicitly typed. For example, because BeanShell is using an interpreter and it resolves types at runtime instead of "compile-time" (which doesn't exist in BeanShell outside of creating an AST, which is parsing, not compiling), this is legal in BeanShell:

```
i.set("xStr", someBigNumber1);
i.set("yStr", someBigNumber2);
i.eval("import java.math.BigDecimal;");
i.eval("x = new BigDecimal(xStr);");
i.eval("y = new BigDecimal(yStr);");
i.eval("result = x.add(y);");
s = i.get("result").toString();
```

Even though I didn't declare `x` and `y` as `BigDecimal`, I can still call `add` on `x` and pass in `y`. This is because when BeanShell is running the code, it knows the concrete types of `x` and `y` and resolves the method on the fly using reflection.

Comment: I copy/pasted your coded above but I receive the error `Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``x = new BigDecimal(xStr);y = new BigDecimal(yStr);result = x.add(y);'' : Unknown class: BigDecimal
        Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``x = new BigDecimal(xStr);y = new BigDecimal(yStr);result = x.add(y);'' : Unknown class: BigDecimal : at Line: 1 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``x = new BigDecimal(xStr);y = new BigDecimal at bsh.BSHAllocationExpression.objectAllocation(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @wasp256 Sorry about that, forgot the `import` statements. You could also reference `BigDecimal` directly, i.e. `new java.math.BigDecimal(xStr);`